# Access LogEntry from views

Tags: django

I am hoping to see LogEntry contents from non-admin views but so far failed. From admin, I can see data of a user who have added actions to LogEntry via log_action method (from non-admin area). But when I tried to see it, I don't see his data. All I see are array data that is full blank values.

```
  from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry
  data=LogEntry.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id).values('change_message',)
```

Here i see fields such as "added","change_message" etc but all are blank. Any help?

Comment: change_message maybe empty, try `data = [str(x) for x in LogEntry.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id)]`

Answer (score 3):

@mounir is right for access change messages of log entry model but we also have method for access change message.

```
data = [ log.get_change_message() for log in LogEntry.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id)]
```

Comment: How would be the same approach for the `get_queryset()` method into a viewset in django-rest-framework?

Comment: `get_queryset` only useful for handle queryset and apply any filter on that.

It's depend on method that return response as a json.
so you can use direct there.

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
    qs = self.get_queryset()
    data = [ log.get_change_message() for log in qs]
    return Response({"data" :data})
```